# (Android) File download normally on one host, but 'completed immediately' on another

Tags: android, sockets, http, networking, download

I'm in a hurry so I'll make this short. If needed, I'll provide more info when I get back to my PC.

I'm creating a download/upload speed test app for Android. Here's some of the code:

```
InetAddress Host = InetAddress.getByName(myHoseName);
Socket s = new Socket(Host,80);

//prepare data stream for each direction
            OutputStream output = s.getOutputStream();
            InputStream input = s.getInputStream();

//send command
            output.write( ("GET "+ myFilePath +" HTTP/1.0\r\n").getBytes() );
            output.write("Accept: */*\r\n".getBytes());
            output.write("\r\n".getBytes());

 while ((DownloadedByte += input.read(BufferData,0,BufferData.length)) != -1)
            {   
                //download started... bla bla bla
```

The problem:

- I have the SAME test file on 2 host. (the name is test.jpg)
- One look like this: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   (it's an IP address)
- Another one is a domain name like my.testhost.com
- The problem is when I try to download from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, everything is fine
- But when I try to download from my.testhost.com, the download process completed immediately with next to nothing being shown on Logcat

I hope this info is enough to get started with the problem. My apology but I'll provide more info later, maybe tomorrow.

Thanks and talk to you soon!

Best,
Kitti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very much like the download from my.testhost.com fails and therefor appears to complete immediately, although it only aborted. Check the downloaded data to rule this out.

A failure can happen due to a variety of reasons. Most likely are that either the hostname does not resolve (the lookup of the IP for the name my.testhost.com does not work), or the host is reachable only through a proxy server that you would need to configure before you can make downloads.

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for answering. I agree with your opinion. I'll see what I can do about proxy. In the mean time, I have more information to share. My team mates who is developing the iOS version of the same speed test app seems to download the file with no problem. But he's using HTTP, not socket.

Comment: This also points towards a proxy problem - if you use sockets, no proxy will be used. If you use some HTTP capable classes, they most likely use the system's proxy settings to locate and use the proxy server. It's a good idea to also use a java.net.URLConnection then, because with this Java's proxy settings will be used automatically. You can grab an input stream from the URLConnection similar to how you grab it from a socket and do the speed test exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Seems like this is the cause. =)